# Unable to run Flutter App on iPhone 11 Pro after upgrading to Flutter 2

Tags: android, iphone, xcode, flutter2.0

I upgraded to Flutter 2 and when I run App on iPhone 11 Pro on Android Studio I get the error below. Running the App on Xcode works fine. Didn't have this problem until I upgraded to Flutter 2.

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳

2021-03-28 20:58:47.597 xcodebuild[26509:183755]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-17705/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-001A5D3221BB802E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9889e5e380>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9888030a60>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2021-03-28 20:58:47.815 xcodebuild[26509:184029]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-17705/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-001A5D3221BB802E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9889e5e380>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9889b8ef80>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2021-03-28 20:58:47.924 xcodebuild[26509:184029]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-17705/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008030-001A5D3221BB802E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9889e5e380>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9889b8ef80>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2021-03-28 20:59:08.937 xcodebuild[26509:183961]  DTDeviceKit: Failed to mount DDI from 'DVTFilePath:0x7f988a733370:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.2/DeveloperDiskImage.dmg'', error=-402653035: Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=806 "Failed to prepare device for development." UserInfo={AssociatedMobileDeviceFunction=AMDeviceMountImage, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9889f3f870 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402653035 "The device rejected the pairing attempt." UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8000095), com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000111769c8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001117a5e8f -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken _mountDeveloperDiskImage:withError:] + 1024
2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001117a68af __58-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:]_block_invoke + 609
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7266d658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff726796ec _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
5   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001117a65ec -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken mountDeveloperDiskImageWithError:] + 188
6   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000110f7554c __28-[DVTiOSDevice attachToken:]_block_invoke_5 + 277
7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100a0517e **DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK** + 7
8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000100a06da0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7266c6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7266d658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7266f818 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 414
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7266ef16 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7267b957 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7267c097 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 92
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff728c79f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff728c6b77 start_wqthread + 15
),

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: Same here, someone found a solution?

Comment: @armstrong I had to downgrade to Flutter v1.